# Are there another way for replacing except for Replace() function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, string

In c programming language,

I can do

```
printf("%d\n", value);
```

But in c#, how can I do it?
For example string is "Good %s everybody"

I want to replace %s with the variable.
Are there any solution except for

```
str.Replace("%s","good morning");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) would be your function of choice.

You then could write e.g.:

```
const string t = "Thomas";
var s = string.Format("Good morning {0}.", t);
```

With `{0}` being replaced with the value of `t`.

Comment: I add to previous example that if you need several format chars (like printf("%d %s %d %s",a,b,c,d);) you must use numbers of argument in brackets: string.Format("Good morning {0}. {2}, {1}", t,"r u?", "How ");

Comment: On the other hand, why do you use const for string t ?

Comment: @GöktürkSolmaz This is just an example to make it simple. You could pass anything that has `.ToString()` (since everything derives from `object` and `object.ToString()` exists, this is the case with all objects).